# method is undefined for class main

Tags: java

I'm writting a simple model of a social media where a users friends is represented as an array of `Friend` objects.

I am getting the titled error with the use of the method `toStringFriends` used in the main method. Doe anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
public class Friend {

private String name;
private String password;
private int uid;
private Friend [] friends;

public Friend (String name, String password, int uid, Friend [] friends) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.friends [0] = friends [0];

}

public Friend [] getFriends () {
    return friends;
}

public String toStringFriends (Friend [] friends) {     
    String s = "";  
    for (int i = 0; i <= friends.length; i++) {
         s = s + (friends [i]).getName();
    }
    return s;
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Friend [] noFriends = new Friend [0];

    Friend [] laurasFriends = new Friend [1];           

    Friend jack = new Friend ("jack","liverpool",1,noFriends);  

    laurasFriends [0] = jack;

    Friend laura = new Friend ("laura","everton",2,laurasFriends);

    String s = toStringFriends(laurasFriends);
    System.out.println(s);  

    System.out.println(toStringFriends(laura.getFriends()));
}
}
```

Comment: How can you access a method of another class without creating an object or accessing it statically?

Comment: `i <= friends.length` looks like an index out of bounds exception to me (valid indices are `0` to `fields.length - 1`). You shouldn't make us guess though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch He isn't getting that far - see the error in the question title.

Comment: not related to the title but hes going to have issues with the Friends constructor because hes not initializing the friends field correctly. Should be `this.friends = friends`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call it from `laura`'s instance of the object:

```
String s = laura.toStringFriends(laurasFriends);
```

Comment: That would work, but I don't think that's what he's intending to do. In that case why pass the friends array in anyway, why not just use the one on the class?

Comment: I agree with you... that code of his would benefit from some refactoring to apply good programming practices

Answer (score 0):

Either make `toStringFriends()` static or instantiate a Friend object and call that method on it.

Comment: True, but can expand on this please? How would you call the method in the first case? Why would you use one not the other?

Comment: If the method is static, you can simply call toStringFriends() from your main method, because the main method is static as well. However, this doesn't quite make sense, because every instance of a Friend will have a different value for this field. Thus, it makes more sense to say Friend friend = new Friend(...); and then call friend.toStringFriends();

Answer (score 0):

Use it by creating Friend class object-

```
Friend friend=new Friend(<constructor input 
parameters>);
friend.toStringFriends(<function input 
parameters>);
```

Or make toStringFriends() static and call it by using Friend class.

Answer (score 0):

`toStringFriends` has access to `friends` and `name` so I would pass a separator if I passed anything. I would also prefer a `StringBuilder` to using `String` concatenation in a loop. And I don't see a `getName()` in your class, but `Friend` has access to its' own data. Then `<=` is going to cause an array index out of bounds exception, because valid array indices are `0` to `friends.length - 1`. So you can do something like,

```
public String toStringFriends(String sep) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(sep);
        }
        sb.append(friends[i].name);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then change `this.friends [0] = friends [0];` to `this.friends = friends;` in your constructor, and finally call `toStringFriends` like

```
String s = laura.toStringFriends(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an instance or non static method without object.  You should use some instance object and then you can call via `.` operator.
Like `object.method()`